# Rest Controller isn't asynchronous

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous

I am trying to create asynchronous REST API. Every call starts service method which takes 2 seconds to finish. I would like to make 20 calls at the same time and start all this methods on different threads so my controller would not be blocked and I could get all responses in about ~ 2 sec.

I tried adding @Asnyc annotation to both Controller, and service, but they were giving me empty response, after adding CompletableFuture as response I am getting proper response but now it is not async and I need to wait about 40 sec for all responses.

```
@RestController
public class BasicController{


    @Autowired
    private BasicService basicService;

    @Async("asyncExecutor")
    @GetMapping("/basic/{owner}/{path}")
    public CompletableFuture<InfoDTO>getGitApiInfo(@PathVariable("owner") String owner,
                                                   @PathVariable("path") String path) throws InterruptedException {
        return basicService.getRepositoryInfo(owner, path);
    }

}



@Service
public class BasicService{


    @Async("asyncExecutor")
    public CompletableFuture<InfoDTO> getRepositoryInfo(String owner, String repoName) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(new InfoDTO(owner, repoName);
    }

}


@EnableAsync
@Configuration
public class ServicesConfig {

    @Bean(name = "asyncExecutor")
    public Executor asyncExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(8);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(20);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(500);
        executor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("Async-");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }
}
```

I would like to get 20 responses from this controller in about 2-3 sec using postman runner.

Comment: If you make 20 concurrent requests to a controller, the 20 concurrent requests will be handled in parallel without having to use Async or anything else. Because the container has a pool of threads to handle requests, and the pool has much more than 20 threads. So if you get the responses in 40 seconds, it means that either the client sends the requests sequentially, or you have some lock somewhere in the code preventing requests to be handled concurrently.

Comment: I know nothing about postman runner, but I know that `ab` (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/ab.html) is a very easy to use tool to send concurrent requests to a server.

Comment: It works, thank You for clarification. Problem was with postman, it can't send many http requests concurrently. I tested it with apache jMeter and now it works like a charm.